# Generate Specific Kind of Table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to format a table in latex to look like the image I've attached; however, I don't know how to create a new row that isn't affected by the formatting of the previous ones. Thank you for your help, and apologies for the mediocore illustration. [image: Apologies for the bad microsoft paint drawing]

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{<stuff>}`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks!